# Error on SSIS creating package to dump data from database to to csv file

Tags: sql-server, ssis, package

Hi I am creating a pretty simple package to dump my data from a database to a csv file.
I am getting the command line screen followed by an error message.
A csv file was created but had the following error messg.
I have tested the connection and it says successful , but I am getting the same error although I  increased the MaximumErrorCount parameter to 5 for the for the Execute Process Task.
Any help would be appreciated since I don't know how to figure out the debug.

This is what I get as error:

```
    Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0 : Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [2]. .
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0 : Login timeout expired.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0 : A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while
 establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. 
 Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online..
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL Server connection manager seems to be the problem.

[image]

The error message is showing a login-connection timeout. Double-click the SQL Server connection manager, and verify that you are able to test the connection successfully.

[image]
If you get errors (ex: access denied, bad password etc) fix them until you get a successfully connected message

[image]

Comment: Hi @Shiva I was  suspecting it, but I have my server up and running. I have tried solutions from this tuto below but it doesn t seem to work. I have passed the connection Manager Test, but doesnt seem to work. https://www.youtube.com/playlist?annotation_id=annotation_850415&feature=iv&list=PL4BD5C24EDB584162&src_vid=1k00z82u4OI. still cant get my head around it

Comment: What happens when you try the "Test Connection". From the error message, it is clear that the problem is on the SQL Server connection, not on the flat file destination. Also, what is being done in the "dump data in csv" expression?

Comment: when I test  after filing in details, I have error mssg, but When I fill all other details for foreach loop container and retest the connection, only then it test ok. However, although it doesnt connect when I am filling the Collection tab, I am still able to access database and table. Then after , when I leave and ok, and test the connection manager , only then it seems to be successful. That why I proceed to Process Task

Comment: ok. Little difficult to troubleshoot this at this level, as it seems like a lot is going on in the SSIS package / code.

Comment: just had a pic. Also good to know that I am using I am using the foreach SMO Enumerator as the big container and the Execute ProcessTask

Comment: Thanks. So something else going on in your expression task.